# reading a text files in Scala

Tags: linux, scala

I have been trying to read text files using Scala one line at a time

```
scala> import scala.io.Source
scala> val filename = "read from file"

scala> for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
      {
        println(line)
      }
```

But upon typing the the last line on the terminal,I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open file scala (No such file or directory)
  at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
  at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
  at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
... 32 elided
```

Comment: The filename in the code you shared and the error do not match. Anyway, the error seems to simply be that the file your looking for is not there. Double check that the file name is valid and present in the working directory of your REPL. You can check the working directory with `java.nio.file.Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the correct full path to the file into `filename`.

Something like `/home/username/workdir/some_file.txt`.